# Spring boot application with embedded tomcat, send access logs to syslog

Tags: spring-boot, logback, syslog, access-log

I have a spring boot application, which runs on AWS EC2 instances.

The deployable is just a jar that has tomcat embedded in it.

I am trying to get the application to send its access log to syslog so that I can use AWS CloudWatch to collect logs from different EC2 instances.

I have tried https://logback.qos.ch/access.html, but it does not work with syslog due to this issue: https://jira.qos.ch/browse/LOGBACK-317

Then I tried CommonsRequestLoggingFilter, this does not seem to send its logs to syslog.

I guess trying to send logs to syslog with Spring boot application is not a rare desire.

Is there any comprehensive way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tomcat access logging through log4j?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18056682/tomcat-access-logging-through-log4j)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just implemented this in my application. (For Spring boot 1.5.6)

1. Make sure your tomcat access logging is on, below is the way access logging is enabled in application.yml -

   ```
   server: 
    tomcat:
     accesslog:
       enabled: true
       pattern: "<APPNAME> %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %s %b %D"
       prefix: "localhost_access_log"
       suffix: .txt
     basedir: /opt/tomcat
   ```
2. The above will output the access logs in your instances.
3. Now have your logging defined. For example in application.yml file

   ```
   logging:
     level:
       org.springframework.web: INFO
       com.project.path : DEBUG
     config: <path to your config xxml>/logback-springboot.xml
   ```
4. The above will get your logback config file from the desired location.
5. Now, in your code, you need to define your own tomcat access config. For example -

   ```
   @Configuration
   public class AccessValveConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter implements
    EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer {

    private static XLogger logger = XLoggerFactory
       .getXLogger(AccessValveConfig.class);


    @Override
     public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {

        if (container instanceof TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) {

           TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory factory = 
                 (TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) container;
           AbstractAccessLogValve accessLogValve = new ApiAccessLogValve();
           accessLogValve.setPattern("common");
           factory.addContextValves(accessLogValve);
        } else {
        logger.error("WARNING! this customizer does not support your 
                configured container");
       }
    }
   }

   public class ApiAccessLogValve extends AbstractAccessLogValve {

     private static XLogger logger = XLoggerFactory
       .getXLogger(ApiAccessLogValve.class);

     public ApiAccessLogValve(){
      super();
     }

    @Override
    protected void log(CharArrayWriter message) {
      synchronized (this) {
       logger.info(message.toString());
      }
    }
   }
   ```
6. Now make the necessary configs in your logback xml.

   ```
   <!--This will print app logs in user facility-->
   <appender name="SYSLOG" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SyslogAppender">
    <syslogHost><<your host name>></syslogHost>
    <port>514</port>
    <facility>USER</facility>
    <suffixPattern><<your pattern>></suffixPattern>
   </appender>
   <!-- This will print your access logs in local0 facility-->
   <appender name="LOCAL0" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SyslogAppender">
     <syslogHost><<your host name>></syslogHost>
     <port>514</port>
     <facility>LOCAL0</facility>
     <suffixPattern><<pattern>></suffixPattern>
   </appender>

   <Logger name="package path to ApiAccessLogValve" level="INFO" 
       additivity="false">
      <appender-ref ref="LOCAL0" />
   </Logger>
   ```

Now you are all set.